# Is there a way disable the "similar commands" feature on the VSCode Command Palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on automating our VSCode extension and we're having issues with the "new" VSCode functionality to show commands that are similar to the command palette search (I know it's a great QoL feature, but it's not helping on this case) as it's mudding the results the automation is getting.

[image]

So, do you know if there's an option to disable the "similar commands" feature or a better way to access the specific command?

PD: I've found this setting, but the list seems to be unaffected:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, toggling that setting off does remove any `similar commands` listing for me.  Are you using the latest version of vscode?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Also include which extension you have which provides the natural language support and what version of it you have installed.